# Add progressbar as compoundDrawable to button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, android-progressbar

I want to add a indeterminate progressbar to my custom button.
I'm using add `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` to add it to left.
But somehow progress bar animation doesn't appear.

```
//CustomButton.kt
fun addProgressbar () {
  val progressBar = ProgressBar(context)
  progressBar.isIndeterminate = true
  progressBar.animate()
  progressBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
  progressBar.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
  )
  progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

  setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
      progressBar.indeterminateDrawable,
      null,
      ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_black_24),
      null
  )
}
```

When I debug `progressBar.isAnimating()` returns `false`. I also tried to add a resource drawable with `ContextCompat.getDrawable` which works.

How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    private var progressDrawable: Drawable

    init {
        progressDrawable = ProgressBar(context).indeterminateDrawable.apply {
            // apply any customization on drawable. not on progress view
            setBounds(0, 0, 24.toPx, 24.toPx)
            setTint(Color.WHITE)
        }
        compoundDrawablePadding = 4.toPx
    }

    var isLoading: Boolean = false
        set(value) {
            if (isLoading == value) return
            field = value

            val (startDrawable, topDrawable, endDrawable, bottomDrawable) = compoundDrawablesRelative
            if (value) {
                // add progress and keep others
                setCompoundDrawablesRelative(
                    progressDrawable,
                    topDrawable,
                    endDrawable,
                    bottomDrawable
                )
                (progressDrawable as? Animatable)?.start()
            } else {
                // remove progress
                setCompoundDrawablesRelative(
                    null,
                    topDrawable,
                    endDrawable,
                    bottomDrawable
                )
                (progressDrawable as? Animatable)?.stop()
            }
        }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        (progressDrawable as? Animatable)?.stop()
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    }
}
```

[image: Progress button]

PS: Slowness is related to recording/encoding. It works normally.

Comment: Hey thanks, that actually worked. I most likely forgot to accept it back then :)